# Sorting using orderBy in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby, ng-options

My code is :

```
<select ng-model="i.br" ng-options="item.name as info[item.name] for item in e.br | orderBy:info[item.name]" class="combobox">
```

Here the orderBy is not sorting according to the info[item.name].

```
e.br is an array like :
0:object (object is name:'abc')
1:object (object is name:'xyz')
..
.
.
.

and info is a hash like :
{
'abc' : '123abc'
'xyz' : '456xyz'
}
```

Any possible way that I want to show 123abc and sort according to these but keep the value of the model as abc

Comment: please provide more details or plunker demo the language of question is little confusing

Comment: Yeah thanks for the -1. Dunno why people abuse this downvote thingy ...i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Hashes can't be sorted in Javascript, so you'll need to convert your `info` hash into an array.